# get Printprogress in xul printing

Tags: printing, xul, xulrunner

I am doing this xul offline application which has lots of print job. Is there anyway to get the progress/listener from xul print, saying it is complete? I am stuck with this for sometime now, please share some ideas on how to proceed. The code for printing is as follows.

### xul file

```
<iframe type="content-primary" flex="1" src="index.html"  />
```

### Print Function

```
function getWebBrowserPrint()
{
return _content.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
.getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPrint);
}

function printpdf() {
var webBrowserPrint= getWebBrowserPrint();
var gPrintSettings = webBrowserPrint.globalPrintSettings;

gPrintSettings.footerStrLeft = "";
gPrintSettings.footerStrCenter = "";
gPrintSettings.footerStrRight = "";
gPrintSettings.headerStrLeft = "";
gPrintSettings.headerStrCenter = "";
gPrintSettings.headerStrRight = "";
gPrintSettings.printSilent = true;
gPrintSettings.showPrintProgress = true;
gPrintSettings.printerName = "PDF Writer";
webBrowserPrint.print(gPrintSettings, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to `webBrowserPrint.print` can be an [nsIWebProgressListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWebProgressListener) object. In particular you'll get an `onStateChange` callback with a flag including `STATE_STOP` when printing has finished.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference on how it is done ? I tried doing with html2pdf sample application without any success

Comment: @Sullan Sorry, your comment is a bit vague, it's unclear what you would like to have additional help on.